# Cant validate radio checked properly as DOM returns values before validation is executed

Tags: javascript

Sorry for the tittle might be quite confusing.

I have a radio check box, if clicked once it gets checked if clicked again it gets unchecked.

```
<label class='container'><p1 style='font-size: 14px'>Able to fit several products</p1>
<input type='radio' name='Delivery' id='Delivery' onclick='radio_check();'>
<span class=checkmark></span>
</label>

var radio = document.getElementById("Delivery")
if(radio.checked){
   radio.checked = false;
}else{
   radio.checked = true;
}
```

The problem with this code is that it will always return radio.checked = false. If the radio is unchecked and user checked it, this function would still return false because the value send to this is that the radio was checked, how can i fix this issue?

https://jsfiddle.net/o2ayejz9/

Comment: does replacing your if...else block with `radio.checked = !radio.checked` solve it?=

Comment: No it doesnt matter what way i do the if. its because the value send to this function will always be true.  The radio starts unchecked, once user press check, the function is executed, the idea would be to return true, but the radio from Delivery will already be set to true, which means the if statement will think its checked already therefore return false

Comment: can you please post the complete click handler and also the html code?

Comment: For some reason on the jsfiddle website the check is working but i cant uncheck. still some issue with it

Comment: why do you use a `radio` if you only want `true` and `false`? try using `checkbox`

Comment: That makes sense, i just tried to re used the code.

Answer (score 0):

use `checkbox` instead of `radio`

https://jsfiddle.net/o2ayejz9/1/

```
<input type='checkbox' name='Delivery' id='Delivery' onclick='radio_check();'>
```

updated your fiddle